# Hibernate 4.2.2 not validating entity upon insertion into its @OneToMany Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have a parent entity with OneToMany association to its children:

```
Parent {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Size(min = 0, max = 4)
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

    @Transactional
    public void addChild(Child child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

When I invoke `addChild()` method, Hibernate doesn't validate the children Collection @Size constraint and persists child 'as is' which leads to invalid entity in a database.

Why Hibernate doesn't validate the parent entity?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate triggers INSERT for the child entity but doesn't triggers UPDATE for the parent entity. I have debugged Hibernate sources and found out that `org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:isUpdateNecessary()` returns `false` in the described above case. Looks like it is a bug that must be fixed.

One possible solution is to make a 'fake' change which would dirties the entity and would trigger the validation process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that hibernate should validate at the moment of invocation of "add" method, usually the validation is triggered on persist ( or might be some other cases ).

```
/**
 * @author Zilvinas Vilutis
 */
public class CollectionSizeTest {

    private final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    private final Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    public class CollectionSize {
        @Size( min = 0, max = 1 )
        private Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    @Test
    public void testCollectionSize() {
        CollectionSize underTest = new CollectionSize();
        assertTrue( validator.validate( underTest ).isEmpty() );

        underTest.collection.add( "first" );
        assertTrue( validator.validate( underTest ).isEmpty() );

        underTest.collection.add( "second" );
        assertEquals( 1, validator.validate( underTest ).size() );
        assertEquals( "size must be between 0 and 1", validator.validate( underTest ).iterator().next().getMessage() );
    }

}
```

Comment: The method is annotated as @Transactional - persist() would be called implicitly

Comment: I wonder how this `@Transactional` works for you on a domain entity class as `Spring` attaches its aspects on spring beans defined on the package scanning config. I would recommend to move this out to a service.

Comment: It's a @Configurable class in my case and I'm using active record pattern intentionally. Thanks for advise, though ;)